# how to expand customPinWinod in xamarin forms maps

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have this custom renderer for iOS and Im uisng xamarin forms maps:

```
public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer
{
UIView customPinView;
ObservableCollection<CustomPin> customPins;

protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (e.OldElement != null)
    {
        var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
        nativeMap.GetViewForAnnotation = null;
        nativeMap.CalloutAccessoryControlTapped -= OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped;
        nativeMap.DidSelectAnnotationView -= OnDidSelectAnnotationView;
        nativeMap.DidDeselectAnnotationView -= OnDidDeselectAnnotationView;
    }

    if (e.NewElement != null)
    {
        var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
        var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
        customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;

        nativeMap.GetViewForAnnotation = GetViewForAnnotation;
        nativeMap.CalloutAccessoryControlTapped += OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped;
        nativeMap.DidSelectAnnotationView += OnDidSelectAnnotationView;
        nativeMap.DidDeselectAnnotationView += OnDidDeselectAnnotationView;
    }
}

protected override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)
{
    MKAnnotationView annotationView = null;

    if (annotation is MKUserLocation)
        return null;

    var customPin = GetCustomPin(annotation as MKPointAnnotation);
    if (customPin == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
    }

    annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation(customPin.Label);
    if (annotationView == null)
    {
        annotationView = new CustomMKAnnotationView(annotation, customPin.Label);
        annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromFile("pin.png");
        annotationView.CalloutOffset = new CGPoint(0, 0);
        annotationView.LeftCalloutAccessoryView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("monkey.png"));
        annotationView.RightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
        ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Name = customPin.Label;

    }
    annotationView.CanShowCallout = true;

    return annotationView;
}

void OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped(object sender, MKMapViewAccessoryTappedEventArgs e)
{
    CustomMKAnnotationView customView = e.View as CustomMKAnnotationView;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customView.Url))
    {
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new Foundation.NSUrl(customView.Url));
    }
}

void OnDidSelectAnnotationView(object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e)
{
    CustomMKAnnotationView customView = e.View as CustomMKAnnotationView;
    customPinView = new UIView();

    var label = new UILabel();
    label.Text = "Tutorial";
    label.Font.WithSize(36);
    customPinView.AddSubview(label);

    customPinView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 200, 84);
    var image = new UIImageView(new CGRect(0, 0, 200, 84));
    image.Image = UIImage.FromFile("xamarin.png");
    customPinView.AddSubview(image);
    customPinView.Center = new CGPoint(0, -(e.View.Frame.Height + 75));
    e.View.AddSubview(customPinView);
}

void OnDidDeselectAnnotationView(object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.View.Selected)
    {
        customPinView.RemoveFromSuperview();
        customPinView.Dispose();
        customPinView = null;
    }
}

CustomPin GetCustomPin(MKPointAnnotation annotation)
{
    var position = new Position(annotation.Coordinate.Latitude, annotation.Coordinate.Longitude);
    foreach (var pin in customPins)
    {
        if (pin.Position == position)
        {
            return pin;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

And I want to add some more things below, and I dont know why it doesnt resize this pin window?
Here is the outcome:[image]

**UPDATE:**
Here is Android renderer which works fine. From my CUstomPinModel, I need dynamically create labels:

```
public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer, GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter
{
    private LatLngBounds.Builder _builder;
    private GoogleMap _map;
    ObservableCollection<CustomPin> customPins { get; set; }
    Context context;
    public CustomMapRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        customPins = new ObservableCollection<CustomPin>();
        _builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    }


    protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            NativeMap.InfoWindowClick -= OnInfoWindowClick;
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
            customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMapReady(GoogleMap map)
    {
        base.OnMapReady(map);

        NativeMap.InfoWindowClick += OnInfoWindowClick;
        NativeMap.SetInfoWindowAdapter(this);
        if (_map == null)
        {
            _map = map;
        }
    }

    protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
    {
        CustomPin customPin = (CustomPin)pin;
        var marker = new MarkerOptions();
        LatLng position = new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude);
        marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude));
        marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
        marker.SetSnippet(pin.Address);
        marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.pin));

        _builder.Include(position);
        LatLngBounds bounds = _builder.Build();

        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngBounds(bounds, 20);

        _map.MoveCamera(cu);

        return marker;
    }

    void OnInfoWindowClick(object sender, GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var customPin = GetCustomPin(e.Marker);
        if (customPin == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
        }
    }

    public Android.Views.View GetInfoContents(Marker marker)
    {
        var inflater = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as Android.Views.LayoutInflater;
        if (inflater != null)
        {
            Android.Views.View view;


            var customPin = GetCustomPin(marker);
            if (customPin == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
            }
                
            view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MapInfoWindow, null);
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.InfoWindowProps);

            if(customPin != null && customPin.InfoBox != null && customPin.InfoBox.DetailsObjectInfos.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < customPin.InfoBox.DetailsObjectInfos.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextView t1 = new TextView(context);
                    t1.Text = customPin.InfoBox.DetailsObjectInfos[i].BoldLabelTitle + customPin.InfoBox.DetailsObjectInfos[i].LabelValue;
                    linearLayout.AddView(t1);
                }
            }

            return view;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Android.Views.View GetInfoWindow(Marker marker)
    {
        return null;
    }

    CustomPin GetCustomPin(Marker annotation)
    {
        var position = new Position(annotation.Position.Latitude, annotation.Position.Longitude);
        foreach (var pin in customPins)
        {
            if (pin.Position == position)
            {
                return pin;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also, I set in my layout correct naming in order to be able to find resource by id:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/InfoWindowImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/monkey" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/InfoWindowProps"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="261.5dp" >

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE #2:**
My model for CustomPin:

```
public class CustomPin : Pin, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string PinIcon { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public InfoBoxMapModel InfoBox { get; set; } = new InfoBoxMapModel();
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public int? ClassId { get; set; }
    public string FavoriteLabel { get; set; }

    public bool? _isFavorite { get; set; }

    public bool? IsFavorite
    {
        get { return _isFavorite; }
        set { _isFavorite = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

}
```

and InfoBoxModel which is containing my string labels:

```
    public class InfoBoxMapModel
    {
        //base64
        public string ImageString { get; set; }
        public ImageSource PinImageSource { get; set; }
        public List<DetailsObjectInfo> DetailsObjectInfos { get; set; } = new List<DetailsObjectInfo>();
        public int CountDetailsItemsRows { get; set; }
    }

    public class DetailsObjectInfo
    {
        public string BoldLabelTitle { get; set; }
        public string LabelValue { get; set; }
    }
```

**UPDATE #3:** Here is the example how it works in android:
[image]
All these rows of strings are concatenation of DetailsObjectInfo => `BoldLabelTitle + ": " + LabelValue`

So, I want to render DetailsObjectyInfos List in white callout pin cloud.

Comment: Hi , which version of Xamarin Forms is used ? The shared code works in my local site with the latest version of Xamarin Forms. You can have a check this official sample whehter works.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/customrenderers-map-pin/

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Im using XF 4.7.0 version. I tried the example on iOS, but I cant find where I can dynamically add new labels like stacked labels. For example, if I have List of strings, I want to present each item as separate label on popup window. I succeeded on ANdroid, but iOS just wont listen to me

Comment: Okey , could you share the effect or code of Android ? This will be helpful to understand the effect correctly.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT please you can find my updated code

Comment: Thanks for updating . I see that the list of strings can be added inside `GetInfoContents` method .I will check the effect how to achieve that in iOS .

Comment: Oh , If want to add subview dynamically , from shared code can not work . Because you need to calculate the frame of Lable each time . If do that will show them. However , there is another way to achieve that , you can use UIStackView to add Label . I will update an answer later show the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need to add subviews dynamically , **the one way** that you need to calculate the `Frame` of each **Control** (`Label`).Such as follow:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    var label = new UILabel();
    label.Frame = new CGRect(50*i, 0, 45, 84);
    label.Text = "Tutorial:"+i;
    label.Font.WithSize(36);
    customPinView.AddSubview(label);
}
```

**The another way** is using **UIStackView** as RootView as follow：

```
void OnDidSelectAnnotationView(object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e)
{
    CustomMKAnnotationView customView = e.View as CustomMKAnnotationView;
    //customPinView = new UIView();
    UIStackView customPinView = new UIStackView();


    if (customView.Name.Equals("Xamarin"))
    {

        //var label = new UILabel(new CGRect(-50, 0, 50, 84));
            

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var label = new UILabel();
            label.Text = "Tutorial:"+i;
            label.Font.WithSize(36);
            customPinView.AddArrangedSubview(label);
        }

        customPinView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 300, 84);
        customPinView.Axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Horizontal;
        customPinView.Distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.EqualSpacing;
        customPinView.Spacing = 10;
        customPinView.Alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Fill;
        customPinView.Center = new CGPoint(0, -(e.View.Frame.Height + 75));
        //customPinView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Yellow;
        e.View.AddSubview(customPinView);
    }
}
```

The effect:

[image]

=============================Update #1===============================

**MainPage** declare the `Lable` text of `Pin`:

```
public partial class MapPage : ContentPage
{
    public MapPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CustomPin pin = new CustomPin
        {
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Position = new Position(37.79752, -122.40183),
            Label = "Xamarin San Francisco Office",
            Address = "394 Pacific Ave, San Francisco CA",
            Name = "Xamarin",
            Url = "http://xamarin.com/about/"
        };
        customMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin };
        customMap.Pins.Add(pin);
        customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(37.79752, -122.40183), Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));
    }
}
```

=============================Update #2#3===============================

Your idea is right . I have found the solution that replace the *adress string* wtih my custom `Label`s .

There is a `DetailCalloutAccessoryView` of `MKAnnotationView` , if we can use custome View for it , it will show the wants.

Modify it inside the `GetViewForAnnotation` method :

```
protected override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)
{
    MKAnnotationView annotationView = null;

    if (annotation is MKUserLocation)
        return null;

    var customPin = GetCustomPin(annotation as MKPointAnnotation);
    if (customPin == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
    }

    annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation(customPin.Name);
    if (annotationView == null)
    {
        annotationView = new CustomMKAnnotationView(annotation, customPin.Name);
        annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromFile("pin.png");
        annotationView.CalloutOffset = new CGPoint(0, 0);
        //annotationView.LeftCalloutAccessoryView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("monkey.png"));
        UIImageView uIImageView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("monkey.png"));
        uIImageView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 75, 100);
        annotationView.LeftCalloutAccessoryView = uIImageView;
        annotationView.RightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
        ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Name = customPin.Name;
        ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Url = customPin.Url;

        customPinView = new UIStackView();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var label = new UILabel();
            label.Text = "Tutorial: " + i;
            label.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
            label.Font.WithSize(36);
            customPinView.AddArrangedSubview(label);
        }
        customPinView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 300, 84);
        customPinView.Axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical;
        customPinView.Distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.EqualSpacing;
        customPinView.Spacing = 1;
        customPinView.Alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Fill;
        annotationView.DetailCalloutAccessoryView = customPinView;

    }
    annotationView.CanShowCallout = true;

    return annotationView;
}
```

This is the full renderer code :

```
public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer
{
    UIStackView customPinView;
    List<CustomPin> customPins;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
            nativeMap.GetViewForAnnotation = null;
            nativeMap.CalloutAccessoryControlTapped -= OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped;
            nativeMap.DidSelectAnnotationView -= OnDidSelectAnnotationView;
            nativeMap.DidDeselectAnnotationView -= OnDidDeselectAnnotationView;
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
            var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
            customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;

            nativeMap.GetViewForAnnotation = GetViewForAnnotation;
            nativeMap.CalloutAccessoryControlTapped += OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped;
            nativeMap.DidSelectAnnotationView += OnDidSelectAnnotationView;
            nativeMap.DidDeselectAnnotationView += OnDidDeselectAnnotationView;
        }
    }

    protected override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)
    {
        MKAnnotationView annotationView = null;

        if (annotation is MKUserLocation)
            return null;

        var customPin = GetCustomPin(annotation as MKPointAnnotation);
        if (customPin == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
        }

        annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation(customPin.Name);
        if (annotationView == null)
        {
            annotationView = new CustomMKAnnotationView(annotation, customPin.Name);
            annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromFile("pin.png");
            annotationView.CalloutOffset = new CGPoint(0, 0);
            //annotationView.LeftCalloutAccessoryView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("monkey.png"));
            UIImageView uIImageView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("monkey.png"));
            uIImageView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 75, 100);
            annotationView.LeftCalloutAccessoryView = uIImageView;
            annotationView.RightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
            ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Name = customPin.Name;
            ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Url = customPin.Url;

            customPinView = new UIStackView();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                var label = new UILabel();
                label.Text = "Tutorial: " + i;
                label.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
                label.Font.WithSize(36);
                customPinView.AddArrangedSubview(label);
            }
            customPinView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 300, 84);
            customPinView.Axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical;
            customPinView.Distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.EqualSpacing;
            customPinView.Spacing = 1;
            customPinView.Alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Fill;
            annotationView.DetailCalloutAccessoryView = customPinView;

        }
        annotationView.CanShowCallout = true;

        return annotationView;
    }

    void OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped(object sender, MKMapViewAccessoryTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomMKAnnotationView customView = e.View as CustomMKAnnotationView;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customView.Url))
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new Foundation.NSUrl(customView.Url));
        }
    }

    void OnDidSelectAnnotationView(object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomMKAnnotationView customView = e.View as CustomMKAnnotationView;
        //customPinView = new UIView();


        if (customView.Name.Equals("Xamarin"))
        {                

            //customPinView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 200, 84);
            //var image = new UIImageView(new CGRect(0, 0, 200, 84));
            //image.Image = UIImage.FromFile("xamarin.png");
            //customPinView.AddSubview(image);
            //customPinView.Center = new CGPoint(0, -(e.View.Frame.Height + 75));
            //e.View.AddSubview(customPinView);
        }
    }

    void OnDidDeselectAnnotationView(object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.View.Selected)
        {
            customPinView.RemoveFromSuperview();
            customPinView.Dispose();
            customPinView = null;
        }
    }

    CustomPin GetCustomPin(MKPointAnnotation annotation)
    {
        var position = new Position(annotation.Coordinate.Latitude, annotation.Coordinate.Longitude);
        foreach (var pin in customPins)
        {
            if (pin.Position == position)
            {
                return pin;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The effect:

[image]

Comment: it works, just can you post a solution where the labels inside the white frame? Instead of "394 Pacific Ave, San Francisco CA" it would be my first label, and the second below, and so on. Thanks

Comment: @Stefan0309 That is the default `Label` of `Pin` , we can't modiy that . You can see that the above `Label`s(`Tutorial:0`,`Tutorial:1`,`Tutorial:2`) can be added , if want the same effect with the default white `Frame` , we need to custom the above custom view .

Comment: Please view my update question. I added my model that Im filling in form api servicer provider. So I dont know how to put that list of strings (labels) into white cloud.

Comment: @Stefan0309 Thanks for updating , I will check that.

Comment: maybe we can hide this main cloud, and then show this (Tutorial:0, Tutorial:1 Tutorial:2)? just an idea..

Comment: Please find my updated question - update #3 I screenshot-ed UI behavior on Android

Comment: @Stefan0309 Oh , it's a good idea . I have udpated the answer with the solution how to achieve that. We can use custom view for `annotationView.DetailCalloutAccessoryView` to achieve that.

Comment: Great! It works! just a question, can I set image a little bit bigger? Ideally, I want left column and a right column, in the left column should be the same image but bigger size or stretched from top to bottom, and in the right column just like this text. Awesome!

Comment: And do you know which method do I need to override to have callback function when user click on the callout, to catch that event in my shared code - I should then do a routing to another detail page for that particular pin. thanks

Comment: @Stefan0309 Yes , you can set image with your wanted `Frame` . Setting `UIImageView` with a defined `Frame` for `LeftCalloutAccessoryView` can achieve that.`UIImageView uIImageView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("monkey.png"));uIImageView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 75, 100);annotationView.LeftCalloutAccessoryView = uIImageView;`

Comment: @Stefan0309 I have updated answer. However , about the callback funtion when user click on the callout , not too much understanding that scene .

Comment: well, when user taps the white cloud that we created..callout, infobox, whatever we call it :)

Comment: @Stefan0309 Okey , I think you can add `GestureRecognizer` for  `DetailCalloutAccessory` to achieve that.For example:`ViewannotationView.DetailCalloutAccessoryView.AddGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: @Stefan0309 If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219256/discussion-between-stefan0309-and-junior-jiang-msft).