# How to create more two labels in Pin using xamarin.forms.maps on iOS Project

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two more objects and want to show it in the pin on the map.

How to create more two fields for this labels in `iOS` project.

In my android project I have two .axml files `MapInfoWindow` and `XamarinMapInfoWindow` and inside I create two more `TextView` with this code:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@id/InfoWindowSubtitle2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="InfoWindowSubtitle2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
         <TextView
            android:id="@id/InfoWindowSubtitle3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="InfoWindowSubtitle2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

But in iOS project I can't find some .axml files.

I use this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/customrenderers-map-pin/)

This is my CustomMapRenderer on iOS project:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using CoreGraphics;
using MaritsaTundzhaForecast;
using MaritsaTundzhaForecast.iOS;
using MapKit;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace MaritsaTundzhaForecast.iOS
{
    public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer
    {
        UIView customPinView;
        List<CustomPin> customPins;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
                nativeMap.GetViewForAnnotation = null;
                nativeMap.CalloutAccessoryControlTapped -= OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped;
                nativeMap.DidSelectAnnotationView -= OnDidSelectAnnotationView;
                nativeMap.DidDeselectAnnotationView -= OnDidDeselectAnnotationView;
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
                var nativeMap = Control as MKMapView;
                customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;

                nativeMap.GetViewForAnnotation = GetViewForAnnotation;
                nativeMap.CalloutAccessoryControlTapped += OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped;
                nativeMap.DidSelectAnnotationView += OnDidSelectAnnotationView;
                nativeMap.DidDeselectAnnotationView += OnDidDeselectAnnotationView;
            }
        }

        protected override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)
        {
            MKAnnotationView annotationView = null;

            if (annotation is MKUserLocation)
                return null;

            var customPin = GetCustomPin(annotation as MKPointAnnotation);
            if (customPin == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
            }

            annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation(customPin.Name);
            if (annotationView == null)
            {
                annotationView = new CustomMKAnnotationView(annotation, customPin.Name);
                annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromFile("pin.png");
                annotationView.CalloutOffset = new CGPoint(0, 0);
                annotationView.LeftCalloutAccessoryView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("monkey.png"));
                annotationView.RightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure);
                ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Name = customPin.Name;
                ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Url = customPin.Url;
                ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).AlertLevel = customPin.AlertLevel;
                ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).CodeNum = customPin.CodeNum;
            }
            annotationView.CanShowCallout = true;

            return annotationView;
        }

        void OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped(object sender, MKMapViewAccessoryTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            CustomMKAnnotationView customView = e.View as CustomMKAnnotationView;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customView.Url))
            {
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new Foundation.NSUrl(customView.Url));
            }
        }

        void OnDidSelectAnnotationView(object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e)
        {
            CustomMKAnnotationView customView = e.View as CustomMKAnnotationView;
            customPinView = new UIView();

            if (customView.Name.Equals("Xamarin"))
            {
                customPinView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 200, 84);
                var image = new UIImageView(new CGRect(0, 0, 200, 84));
                image.Image = UIImage.FromFile("xamarin.png");
                customPinView.AddSubview(image);
                customPinView.Center = new CGPoint(0, -(e.View.Frame.Height + 75));
                e.View.AddSubview(customPinView);
            }
        }

        void OnDidDeselectAnnotationView(object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.View.Selected)
            {
                customPinView.RemoveFromSuperview();
                customPinView.Dispose();
                customPinView = null;
            }
        }

        CustomPin GetCustomPin(MKPointAnnotation annotation)
        {
            var position = new Position(annotation.Coordinate.Latitude, annotation.Coordinate.Longitude);
            foreach (var pin in customPins)
            {
                if (pin.Position == position)
                {
                    return pin;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `CustomMKAnnotationView` file:

```
    using MapKit;

namespace MaritsaTundzhaForecast.iOS
{
    public class CustomMKAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Url { get; set; }

        public int AlertLevel { get; set; }

        public int CodeNum { get; set; }

        public CustomMKAnnotationView(IMKAnnotation annotation, string id)
            : base(annotation, id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "But in iOS project I can't find some .axml files." - iOS does not use AXML for layouts.  If you read the iOS section of the tutorial you link to it explains that you need to modify `OnDidSelectAnnotationView` to display whatever custom UI you want when a pin is tapped.

Comment: Can I get example how to add CustomPin.AlertLevel and CustomPin.CodeNum like a pin field ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63232678/how-to-expand-custompinwinod-in-xamarin-forms-maps